# summing 3 columns and compare

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem with my oracle SQL

```
SELECT BASE_PLATE FROM COMPONENT WHERE THICKNESS = :thicknessVal AND PROJECT_NAME = :projectName AND ((CNC+SCATOR+MANUAL) != QTY_REQUIRED)
```

and the problem is the query is only showing 1 data which it should show 2 datas. any mistake with my query ?

```
BASE_PLATE, NAME,      QTY_REQUIRED,SCATOR,MANUAL,CNC
SMSPW-BS1,  BASE_PLATE,10,          2,     2,     3
SMSPW-BS154,BASE_PLATE,7,           0,     0,     0
SMSPW-BS2,  BASEPLATE, 16,          3,     6,     3
```

Comment: This works fine without the clause on `ThiknessVal`, which doesn't appear in your sample datas. See  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/59c09/1

Comment: Where is `THICKNESS`, `PROJECT_NAME`? What values are bound to `:projectName` and `:thicknessVal`? And also, all three records you supplied satisfy this condition: `(CNC+SCATOR+MANUAL) != QTY_REQUIRED`. Please improve your question.

Comment: sorry guys for not included the :thicknessVal. ThicknessVal and ProjectName is only identifier to show those 3 data entries. and it doesn't have anyproblem at all. all those 3 entries have the same thicknessVa and projectName. The problem is the last filter which is ((CNC+SCATOR+MANUAL) != QTY_REQUIRED)